# Running gulp in `docker-compose build`

Tags: node.js, docker, gulp, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am attempting to include a gulp build process as part of a `docker-compose` build process.

#### Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5.1-onbuild

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm
COPY /app/package.json /usr/src/app/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/app
RUN npm install --only=production
RUN npm install --global gulp-cli
RUN gulp

WORKDIR /
EXPOSE 8080
RUN python3 setup.py install
CMD python3 manage.py ${MODE}
```

#### docker-compose.yml:

```
build: ${REPO}
environment:
    - CONFIG_DIR=/config
    - MODE=production
```

Each time I hit `RUN gulp`, I get the error `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md), gulp expects there to be a `gulpfile.js` in the directory, you only copy package.json. Did you forget to copy that one in?

Comment: That's not it, and actually copying the `package.json` is superfluous, since the initial -onbuild flag copies everything from `/` to `/usr/src/app`.

Comment: Are you sure it's copied in? I didn't see a copy or add directive in the parent image.

Comment: That happens as an `ONBUILD` command in the base image of `FROM python:3.5.1-onbuild`. And I did double check by adding a `RUN ls` in the Dockerfile. Everything was copied in.

Comment: Didn't know about the `ONBUILD` directive, neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue could be that you have installed `nodejs` package and the command expecting `node` in the $PATH. To test this try running `node` on the terminal of the container. You can do this using

```
   docker exec -it <container-hash> bash
```

If that is the error you can symlink `nodejs` to `node` running below command.

```
   ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```